# Image only Aspect fill

Tags: c#, .net, maui

The image that I get does not want to adapt to appear smaller while displaying correctly it is in fill and we see nothing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fictum.Mobile.Views.NewTheoryPage">
    <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0"
                 Orientation="Vertical"
                 VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Picker x:Name="Categories" HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Title="Categories"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCategories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" SelectedItem="{Binding Id}" />

        <Entry Margin="5" 
             Placeholder="Name" x:Name="Name"/>
        <Entry Margin="5"
             Placeholder="Description" x:Name="Description"/>

        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="ic_file_upload.png" x:Name="Image"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150" Aspect="AspectFit"
                            WidthRequest="150" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Upload_Clicked"  />
        
        <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="7" Margin="0,20,0,0"  x:Name="Save" Text="Save" 
                HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="500"
                Clicked="Save_Clicked" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="#BE33FF" FontSize="Body"></Button>

        <Button Margin="0,20,0,0" TextColor="Black" Text="Go Back" Clicked="Go_Back_Clicked" WidthRequest="300"
                HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
FileResult file;
    NewTheoryViewModel theoryViewModel;

    public NewTheoryPage()
    {
        theoryViewModel = new NewTheoryViewModel();
        //activitieViewModel.GetItemCategories().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
        BindingContext = theoryViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void Go_Back_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }

    private async void Upload_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        file = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();

        if (file == null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Attention", "You must select an image!", "Ok");
            return;
        }

        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

        Image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

I tried changing Aspect="AspectFill" to Aspect="Aspect Fit".
I just removed Aspect
I tried to modify the dimensions WidthRequest and HeightRequest

Here is the basic image:

[image: Here is the basic image]

The image received:

[image: The image received]

The expected image:

[image: The expected image]

Default Picture:

[image: Default Picture]

```xml
<ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="fictumimage.jpg" x:Name="Image"
   VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit"
   WidthRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Upload_Clicked"  />
```

Comment: Those two screenshots have nothing in common, as far as I can see. Please double-check them. Consider marking the "wrong" one in red, showing what should move where, or whatever else is wrong, If one of them is showing more XAML than the other, then crop so they correspond to each other and/or draw in red and label the part that corresponds to the other screenshot.

Comment: Also,`Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` have no effect in the code you've shown. Those only work if the IMMEDIATE PARENT is a Grid. `<Grid ...> <SomeElement Grid.Row...> ... </Grid>` will work. `<Grid ...> <SomeLayout> <SomeElement Grid.Row...> </SomeLayout> </Grid>` will have no effect.

Comment: It's ok I changed

Comment: I've fixed how the images display.

Comment: Instead of ImageSource.FromStream, try [ImageSource.FromFIle(filepath)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.imagesource.fromfile).

Comment: There is no filepath?

Comment: You used mediapicker to have user open a file. That file has a path. Look at what mediapicker returned as result.

Comment: Here is what I manage to do to avoid an error: Image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file.FullPath);. But it didn't change anything

Comment: Ok. Undo that change; go back to your `file.OpenReadAsync`.  If you make a separate `<Image x:Name="testImage" ... />` and set its Source, does that show it? (To find out if it is only `ImageButton` that has a problem.)

Comment: Indeed I modified and it works like that (you can see at the bottom I added the image)

Comment: Its good that `ImageButton` works if you set `Source="fictumimage.jpg"`. But that isn't what I meant. I said to add another XAML element, `<Image x:Name="testImage" ...`. Set its source in code, similar to what you did for ImageButton: `testImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(...`.

Comment: it's the same thing

Comment: It fails in the same way as the ImageButton?

Comment: Exactly, do you want me to share the github for you to see more details?

Comment: It will have to be solved by maui devs. Make an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues. Include public github repo link in that iusse. Have code that shows that both Image and ImageButton fail. Make a new project with just enough code to show the failure; just have the imagebutton, image, and code behind that calls mediapicker. Also a link to this question. Then come back to question, add a link to the ISSUE at bottom of question. This will be the easiest way to connect the two.

Comment: It's done : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16076